# Lollipop notation in Rational Software Architect

Tags: uml, rational-rsa

I am using IBM Rational® Software Architect™ for WebSphere® Software Version: 7.5.2.
In a component diagram I would really like to use the lollipop notation and not the stereotyped interface notation for a provided interface part.

Any tips if this is possible in RSA?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it myself :-)

Select the interface, in the Properties view select "Appearance", un-check the "Classifier Shape".

Answer (score 0):

Happy to hear you figured things out.  Next time you might also want to check out the forum for RSA on developerWorks.  There are a ton of developers (IBM support/developers and product users) who contribute to and monitor the questions posted there: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=430

Answer (score 0):

you can do this generically by editing the window>preferences>modelling>uml diagrams>class form.  in that form clear the flag on interface - 'use class shape'.

next time you add an interface it will pick up the new default.  for existing interfaces soft delete (from diagram) and re add them from the model and they come back as lollipop form